# How to find the calling test in cypress custom command

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress

I have a command that overwrites pause to add the input from a dialog to the reports. I want to know if there is a way to know what test is calling the function so that I can customize the message on the inputs.

```
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('pause', (originalFn, element, options) => {
    var tryThis = '';
    if (//place calling the function == file1) {
         tryThis = 'message1';
    } else if (//place calling the function == file2) {
         ...
    } else if (//place calling the function == file3) {
         ...
    }
    var datalog = window.prompt(tryThis, "Log your results");
    cy.addContext("DATALOG:" + datalog);
    return originalFn(element, options)
  })
```

Answer (score 8):

As well as access via the Mocha properties there is also

**For the spec file** [Cypress.spec](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/spec.html#Syntax)

Properties for `my.spec.js`

```js
Cypress.spec.absolute: "C:/.../my.spec.js"  

Cypress.spec.name: "my.spec.js"

Cypress.spec.relative: "cypress\integration\my.spec.js"

Cypress.spec.specFilter: "my"

Cypress.spec.specType: "integration"
```

**For the test** [cy.state('runnable')](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/10/02/debug-a-flaky-visual-regression-test/#duplicate-screenshot-names)

For

```js
describe('my-context', () => {
  it('my-test', () => {
```

Properties and methods,

```js
const title = cy.state('runnable').title;           // "my-test"

const fullTitle = cy.state('runnable').fullTitle(); // "my-context my-test"

const titlePath = cy.state('runnable').titlePath(); // ["my-context", "my-test"]
```

---

You can also add **metadata** to the test

```js
describe('my-context', () => {
  it('my-test', { message: "my-message" },  () => {
```

and grab it in the command overwrite

```js
const message = cy.state('runnable').cfg.message; // "my-message"
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked for me (my version of cypress is 6.1.0):

```
cy.log(Cypress.mocha.getRunner().suite.ctx.test.title);
```

More info: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2972