# Is there a way to access test case and test suite details in Cypress?

Tags: cypress, end-to-end

I am trying to make a JSON file to store the details of Cypress Tests, but I don't know how to access them.
The details I need:
1- Test case (it block) title
2- Test suite (describe block) title
3- Number of current retry
And inside the after each hook
3- Test case state (passed, failed, skipped)
4- Test case duration
5- Test case Error message (in case the test case failed)

Comment: There is modules api and after:run event that exposes those details. They can be found here https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/after-run-api#Syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this question for relevant details:
[How to find the calling test in cypress custom command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66053609/how-to-find-the-calling-test-in-cypress-custom-command)

Also, you can simply copy and use one of these functions:

```js
// To get the test case title (it block description)
function testCaseTitle(inHook){
  if(inHook) // If called inside a hook
    return Cypress.mocha.getRunner().suite.ctx.currentTest.title;
  return Cypress.mocha.getRunner().suite.ctx.test.title;
}



// To get the test suite title (describe block description)
function testSuiteTitle(inHook){
  if(inHook) // If called inside a hook
    return Cypress.mocha.getRunner().suite.ctx._runnable.parent.title;
  return Cypress.mocha.getRunner().suite.ctx.test.parent.title;
}



// To get the current test retry 
function testCaseRetry(inHook){
  if(inHook) // If called inside a hook
    return Cypress.mocha.getRunner().suite.ctx.currentTest._currentRetry;
  return Cypress.mocha.getRunner().suite.ctx.test._currentRetry;
}
// To get the total number of retries
function totalRetries(inHook){
  if(inHook) // If called inside a hook
    return Cypress.mocha.getRunner().suite.ctx.currentTest._retries;
  return Cypress.mocha.getRunner().suite.ctx.test._retries;
}



// To get the test case state in after each hook
function testCaseState(){
  return Cypress.mocha.getRunner().suite.ctx.currentTest.state;
}
// Or Alternatively, to test whether the test case has passed in after each hook
function hasPassed(){
  return Cypress.mocha.getRunner().suite.ctx.currentTest.state == 'passed';
}



// To get the test case duration in seconds in after each hook
function testCaseDuration(){
  return (Cypress.mocha.getRunner().suite.ctx.currentTest.duration/1000).toFixed(2)+' sec';
}



// To get the error message of a failing test case 
function testCaseErrorMessage(){
  return Cypress.mocha.getRunner().suite.ctx.currentTest.err.message;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me to get:

- Suite Title (feature title)
- Test case title (feature scenario desc)

using Cypress 12.5 with mochawesome 7.1.3

---

// support/e2e.js

```
Cypress.on('test:before:run', (attribute, test) => {
featureTitle = test.parent.title;
})

Cypress.on('test:after:run', (test) => {
featureTitleAndScenarioDesc = featureTitle + test.title;
})
```